# JS Object transformation based on values of object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, javascript-objects

I've seen lots of other questions related to js object sorting, most of which tend to suggest using the .map method to sort an object or array of objects based on the value of a property, but I'm trying to achieve something slightly different.

I'm trying to turn this object format:

```
{
    "commits": [
        {
            "repository": "example-repo-1",
            "commit_hash": "example-hash-1"
        },
        {
            "repository": "example-repo-1",
            "commit_hash": "example-hash-1.2"
        },
        {
            "repository": "example-repo-2",
            "commit_hash": "example-hash-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Into an object formatted using the value of 'repository' like this:

```
{
    "example-repo-1": [
        {
            "repository": "example-repo-1",
            "commit_hash": "example-hash-1"
        },
        {
            "repository": "example-repo-1",
            "commit_hash": "example-hash-1.2"
        }
    ],
    "example-repo-2": [    
        {
            "repository": "example-repo-2",
            "commit_hash": "example-hash-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I need to get my original object, which is an object with an array of other objects, to return an object which contains numerous arrays, named after the values of the repository property and containing each object that matches that property value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method

```js
var data = {
  "commits": [{
    "repository": "example-repo-1",
    "commit_hash": "example-hash-1"
  }, {
    "repository": "example-repo-1",
    "commit_hash": "example-hash-1.2"
  }, {
    "repository": "example-repo-2",
    "commit_hash": "example-hash-2"
  }]
};

var res = {};

data.commits.forEach(function(v) {
  // define the pproperty if already not defined
  res[v.repository] = res[v.repository] || [];
  // push the reference to the object or recreate depense on your need
  res[v.repository].push(v);
})

console.log(res);
```

---

or using **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** method

```js
var data = {
  "commits": [{
    "repository": "example-repo-1",
    "commit_hash": "example-hash-1"
  }, {
    "repository": "example-repo-1",
    "commit_hash": "example-hash-1.2"
  }, {
    "repository": "example-repo-2",
    "commit_hash": "example-hash-2"
  }]
};

var res = data.commits.reduce(function(obj, v) {
  // define property if not defined
  obj[v.repository] = obj[v.repository] || [];
  // push the object
  obj[v.repository].push(v);
  // return the result object
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```js
var input = {
    "commits": [
        {
            "repository": "example-repo-1",
            "commit_hash": "example-hash-1"
        },
        {
            "repository": "example-repo-1",
            "commit_hash": "example-hash-1.2"
        },
        {
            "repository": "example-repo-2",
            "commit_hash": "example-hash-2"
        }
    ]
};

var output = {};

input.commits.forEach(function(el){
  if(!output[el.repository])
    output[el.repository] = [];
   output[el.repository].push[el];
  })
console.log(output);
```